# Action by Orthogonal Matrices is Transitive

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times k$ real matrices with orthonormal columns, where $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Suppose $\text{col}(A) = \text{col}(B)$ and $A^TA = B^TB = I_k$.

I want to show that there is a $k \times k$ orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $AQ = B$.

My attempts thus far have involved reading about $QR$-factorization.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Small correction: do you mean $A^TA =B^TB=I_k$?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are full-rank, let $Q$ be an invertible linear transformation such that $AQ=B$ and $BQ^{-1}=A$.

Since $A^TA=I_k$, we have that $A^TAQ=A^TB$, and so $Q=A^TB$.
Likewise, we have $B^TBQ^{-1}=B^TA$, and so $Q^{-1}=B^TA$.

From this we see that $Q^T = (A^TB)^T = B^TA = Q^{-1}$, so $Q$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Where do I use the fact that the column spaces are identical?

Comment: This guarantees that an *invertible* linear transformation exists between $A$ and $B$. If the column space of $B$ was smaller, the mapping $Q: col(A) \rightarrow col(B)$ would not be injective and therefore not invertible.

Comment: So $Q$ is the coordinate matrix of the transformation sending $\text{col}_i(A) \mapsto \text{col}_i(B)$ for each $i$?

Comment: If by $col_i(A)$ you mean "the $i^{th}$ column of $A$", then yes you are correct. You can think of $A$ as some collection of $k$ column vectors, and $B$ as some other collection of $k$ column vectors, and $Q$ as the unique map that transforms one set into the other.

Comment: Since two matrices are column equivalent iff their column spaces are equal, I'm going to view $Q$ as the invertible matrix that "column reduces" $A$ to $B$.  (It will be a product of elementary matrices.)  Thanks again for your help!